# Написать свою FTP  на Java, реально?

Tags: ftp, java

Написать свою FTP  на Java, реально?

Comment: Реально написать что угодно на чем угодно ) Клиент или сервер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, почитайте тут - может появятся идеи: [Java FTP client libraries reviewed](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html?page=1).

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, реально. Разбираемся с сокетами и довольно простым протоколом FTP. Сам как-то писал клиент на чистом С без библиотек. Все довольно просто.